# Form submission returns blank page

Tags: php, html, forms, contact-form

I have a contact form that has worked well so far. However, since I created a php router on the site, after submitting the form, although it redirects to the action site (thank-you.php), the site's content is only a blank page (with no HTML content in he body, I checked with dev tools), and the message does not reach the appropriate email address. If I var_dump the $_POST variable on the form submission page, no value is displayed.

I suspect that the problem is related to the router. As a test, I put a "print" PHP command with a number in ascending order before each route. I put the thank-you page (form submission page) directly after the index page to rule out whether the code got stuck on other routes. The strange thing is that, although each sub-page only prints out the numbers up to the place where the given page is among the routers, the thank-you page prints out all the numbers, i.e. those also that would only come after it in the queue... I would be really grateful for some help with this issue. Thank you in advance.

HTML (the form):

```
                <form class="contact-form" method="POST" action="/thank-you">

                    <input type="text" id="website" name="website" />

                    <div class="contact-wrapper name">
                        <label for="name">
                            <?php echo $lang["contact-name"] ?>
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['name-placeholder'] ?>" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contact-wrapper email-and-phone">
                        <div>
                            <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['email-placeholder'] ?>" required>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <label for="telephone">
                                <?php echo $lang["contact-telephone"] ?>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" id="telephone" name="telephone" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['telephone-placeholder'] ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contact-wrapper subject">
                        <label for="subject">
                            <?php echo $lang["contact-subject"] ?>
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['subject-placeholder'] ?>" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="contact-wrapper message">
                        <label for="message">
                            <?php echo $lang["contact-message"] ?>
                        </label>
                        <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['message-placeholder'] ?>" style="height:200px" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo $lang['contact-submit'] ?>">
                </form>
```

PHP (the form submission page):

```
<?php

// exit if accessed directly.
defined('ABSPATH') || die(header('location: /home'));

if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] != '' && $_POST['submit'] != null) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $mailFrom = $_POST['email'];
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $mailTo = "myemailaddress@gmail.com";
    $txt = "You have received an e-mail from " . $name . ".\n\n" . "E-mail: " . $mailFrom . ".\n\n" . "Telephone: " . $telephone . ".\n\n" . $message;

    mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' />
    <title>Thank you!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="thank-you-wrapper">
        <p>Thank you for reaching out to us. We will get back to you shortly. Please click <a href="/home" style="text-decoration: none; color: #0986d9;">here </a> if you are not redirected within a few seconds.
</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.replace("/home"); // will redirect to main page
        }, 3000); // will call the function after 3 secs.
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

PHP (the router):

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/router.php';

// ##################################################
// ##################################################
// ##################################################

// Static GET
// In the URL -> http://localhost

print '1';
// The output -> Index
get('/', 'pages/index.php');

print '2';
// The output -> Thank You
get('/thank-you', 'pages/thank-you.php');

print '3';
// The output -> About
get('/about', 'pages/about.php');

print '4';
// The output -> Services
get('/services', 'pages/services.php');

print '5';
// The output -> Web
get('/web', 'pages/web.php');

print '6';
// The output -> Contact
get('/contact', 'pages/contact.php');
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The router defines `/thank-you` as `GET`:

```
get('/thank-you', 'pages/thank-you.php');
```

while your form is sent via `POST`:

```
<form class="contact-form" method="POST" action="/thank-you">
```

Comment: Ah, okay. So I simply change the form method to GET? But isn't it unsecure for sensitive data?

Comment: Neither POST nor GET is secure or insecure. Security should be in the transport layer (HTTPS). But I'd rather change the router to use POST because GET sends all data in query string which you usually not wan user to see in URL are of the browser.

Comment: W3Schools says that GET is not safe because the form data is visible in the URL

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

Anyway, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: it's unsafe in the way user will see `GET` form data in the URL of their browser and will be able to i.e. manually edit and resent such doctored form. But it can be done the same way with `POST` too. It needs little bit more work and knowledge but that can easily be achieved with dev tools in browser. So you want to use POST for  **most** of forms, because they are usually too big to even fit in browser string. But sometimes you want user to have it in URL string as well to i.e. allow use to bookmark such action (like filtering, query etc). It's nothing about real security. It's rather U/X

Comment: Mainly with GET the insecurity comes if you put sensitive data into the URL such as personal info or passwords, and that can then be logged by servers or visible to others watching over your shoulder, or kept in the browser history, because it's part of the URL. None of that generally happens with POST data because its inside the body of the request